# Batch that rename if the filename lenght is 3 or 4 characters

Tags: windows, batch-file

please a would lile do a batch that analyze the lenght of a filename

```
for example: hello.txt is 5 characters (H E L L O)
for example: cat.txt is 3 characters (C A T)
for example: folders.txt is 7 characters (F O L D E R S)
```

and do this:

if the filename lengh is 3 characters `(for example CAT.txt)` add 2 zeros after the the first character of the filename: so in this case the batch have to rename CAT.txt onto C00AT.txt

if the lengh is 4 characters `(for example CATS.txt)` add 1 zeros after the the first character of the filename: so in this case the batch have to rename CATS.txt onto C0ATS.txt

How can I do? thanks a lot

Comment: There are [many examples of renaming files](https://www.google.com/#q=stackoverflow%20batch%20file%20rename) in a folder. On stack Overflow it is required that you do a research and try something, then we help with the code.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@echo off
set "file=cat.txt"
for %%f in (%file%) do set "filename=%%~nf"
echo old file: %filename%
if "%filename:~2,1%"=="" goto skip
if "%filename:~4,1%"=="" goto renfile
goto skip
:renfile
if "%filename:~3,1%"=="" goto renfile3
set "newfile=%file:~0,1%0%file:~1%"
ren %file% %newfile%
goto done
:renfile3
set "newfile=%file:~0,1%00%file:~1%"
ren %file% %newfile%
goto done
:skip
:done
pause
```

Note that this (as you asked) only renames files with 3 and 4 characters in the name and not those with less.

Next  time when you ask a question, try to show you put some effort into it yourself by showing the code you tried. StackOverflow is a site for programmers to help eachother with their code, not a site for people to write your code for you.

Comment: If you feel like my answer solved my problem you should click the check to the left of it to mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below is designed to rename the files located in current folder, but a simple modification would allow to analyze just one name.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

dir /B *.txt > fileNames.tmp
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /R "^...\." fileNames.tmp') do (
   set "name=%%a"
   ECHO ren "%%a" "!name:~0,1!00!name:~1!"
)
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /R "^....\." fileNames.tmp') do (
   set "name=%%a"
   ECHO ren "%%a" "!name:~0,1!0!name:~1!"
)
del fileNames.tmp
```